# How do I make this python turtle code smaller so it becomes a class?

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

I am writing a piece of code that draws a very simple "tree" recursively. It's a set of functions along with a few "set up" lines, however, I would like to integrate it to a bigger program, so I would like to put this under a class to then call it to draw the tree.

My question is, being new to python, how do I do it? I read about `__init__` and `self.()`, but my code seems to be very fuzzy, all over the place and not compact enough to neatly transform it into a class.

How should I first reduce the lines of code so it all fits into functions?

```
import turtle as t
import random
def arbre(branche,t):
    if branche > 5:
        t.forward(branche)
        t.right(20)
        arbre(branche-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        arbre(branche-15,t)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branche)
def main():

    t.up()
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    arbre(90,t)

for k in range(0,17):
    t.left(10)
    main()

t.right(80)
t.backward(50)
t.penup()
t.forward(25)
t.pendown()
t.right(60)
for k in range(0,11):
    t.left(10)
    main()
```

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what a class actually is. None of this code actually makes sense as a class. Also, there's no limit on how much code you can put into a function or class.

Comment: This depends on your purpose for the class: what objects and methods does it have?  Which parts are parametrized?  Is this "main" method part of the class?  What comes with initialization?  What parts does the calling program do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your class regardless your code's length, but you can reduce your code like this:

```
import turtle as t
t.tracer(2,1) # pour accelerer le dessin
def arbre(branche,t):
    if branche > 5:
        t.forward(branche)
        t.right(20)
        arbre(branche-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        arbre(branche-15,t)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branche)

def main( n ):
    for k in range( n ):
        t.left(10)
        arbre(90,t)

t.color("green")
main(17)

t.right(80)
t.backward(50)
t.penup()
t.forward(25)
t.pendown()
t.right(60)

main(10)
```